# Auditing SQL tables when using Azure AD

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory

In our SQL tables we have columns such as `UpdatedBy` and `CreatedBy` with a ref key to a `User` table. This is useful to keep track of who created/updated an business entity.

However we are migrating from this local User table to using Azure AD. We will use Azure AD for authentication and authorization in our client applications.

There should be no need for a local User table (or any other tables related to identity, such as Role etc...), but then how do I reference user ids from Azure AD into my audit columns? Obviously I can no longer have a reference key with constraint.

What is the usual approach to this?

Comment: You still a local User table... it just ha to haves a way of identifying the AD user and you might automatically populate it.

Comment: not sure I follow you. Do you mean I can keep a User table and have a reference to the Azure AD user id ?

Comment: Yeah, although when last did that I just used the AD username.

Comment: so if I got you right, you do all the authentication/authorization in azure ad, but you keep a local user table with a reference to the ad username so that in your model/db you have a reference to the user  ? But you don't use the local table other than joining on it to see who created/updated what ?

Comment: Thats how I would do it. Also consider that if the AD user is deleted at some point, but you don't want your User to be deleted, and it needs to have enough information that you can still do whatever you do even after the AD user has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read about System for Cross-Domain Identity Management (SCIM)? You can provide out of the box mechanism for syncing Users and Groups created in the Azure AD.

There is a whole tutorial about how to do that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups#step-4-integrate-your-scim-endpoint-with-the-azure-ad-scim-client

There is a ready to go CRUD and SCIM based application in C# created by Microsoft https://github.com/AzureAD/SCIMReferenceCode

That will give you a solution what to do for example when Azure AD is removing the user, but you want to keep it.